Create a custom ionic alert with progress bar using ionic 7 angular
I have create a custom ionic alert with a progress bar using Ionic 7 Angular. but not opening the custom alert
Custom Alert Component Template (custom-alert.component.html):
<div class="custom-alert">
  <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline" class="icon-error"></ion-icon>
  <h2 class="title">Wrong OTP</h2>
  <p class="message">Please enter valid 4 digit verification code</p>
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
</div>

Custom Alert Component Styles (custom-alert.component.scss):
.custom-alert {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

  .icon-error {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #ff5252;
  }

  .title {
    margin: 8px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00bcd4;
  }

  .message {
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #757575;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;

    .progress {
      width: 50%; /* Set the progress value as needed */
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #00bcd4;
      animation: progressAnimation 2s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes progressAnimation {
      0% {
        width: 0;
      }
      100% {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}

Custom Alert Component Logic (custom-alert.component.ts):
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-alert',
  templateUrl: './custom-alert.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-alert.component.scss'],
})
export class CustomAlertComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}

Using the custom alert in your page (example in home.page.ts):
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CustomAlertComponent } from '../components/custom-alert/custom-alert.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  constructor(private alertController: AlertController) {}

  async presentCustomAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Alert',
      cssClass: 'custom-alert-class',
      message: '',
      buttons: ['OK'],
      backdropDismiss: false,
    });

    await alert.present();

    const alertElement = document.querySelector('.custom-alert-class .alert-message');
    if (alertElement) {
      alertElement.innerHTML = '<app-custom-alert></app-custom-alert>';
    }
  }
}

Add CSS to global styles (global.scss):
.custom-alert-class .alert-wrapper {
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}

Update the module (app.module.ts):
Ensure your CustomAlertComponent is declared in your AppModule.
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CustomAlertComponent } from './components/custom-alert/custom-alert.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, CustomAlertComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

Now you have a custom Ionic alert with a progress bar that matches the design in the image. You can trigger this alert from any part of your app using the presentCustomAlert method.

Chat-GPT is not helping you correctly. 1st read the documentation on how to create a popover, not an alert. The alert controller your using cannot be cusomizable like you are trying to do. You need to use popover controller. there you can add you custom code. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover
